# Django - Mongoengine: Store extra information in User Object

Tags: python, django, mongoengine

I decided to save extra data about other things in my user object (The object when a user is created and store some information about thinks I have in mind).

The thing is that I don't know what would be better, If create a custom model or add registers to my created document.

I've no idea about custom User model in mongoengine but I tried to add some extra fields in the User Object. I can easily add it in mongo console but I'm getting in trouble working from Django views so I tried something like that but didn't work.

**My model look like:**

```
from django.db import models
from mongoengine import *
class User(Document):
        username = StringField(max_length=120, required=True)
        password = StringField(max_length=120, required=True)
        email = StringField(max_length=120, required=True)
        my_extra_field= StringField(max_length=120, required=False)
```

**And my forms.py looks like**

```
from django import forms
from captcha.fields import CaptchaField
class PostForm(forms.Form):
    user = forms.CharField(max_length=256)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    email = forms.CharField(max_length=256)
    #my_extra_field is not defined because is a fixed value and no need to introduce in the form
```

**And this are the views, were I'm getting in trouble**

```
def post_form_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = PostForm()
    else:
        # A POST request: Handle Form Upload
        form = PostForm(request.POST) # Bind data from request.POST into a PostForm

        # If data is valid, proceeds to create a new post and redirect the user
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.cleaned_data['user']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            my_extra_field = 500
            connect('reborn')
            m = User.create_user(user,password,email)
            m.gold=500
            m.save()
            return HttpResponse(m)
            e.gold = 500
            e.save()
            #john.save()
            #return HttpResponse("Usuari nou creat")
            return render(request, 'game/welcomeuser.html', {
                'user': user,
            })
    return render(request, 'game/post_form_upload.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

I tried different ways but always errors, so:

Option 1:

```
if form.is_valid():
                user = form.cleaned_data['user']
                password = form.cleaned_data['password']
                email = form.cleaned_data['email']
                my_extra_field = 500
                connect('reborn')
                m = User.create_user(user,password,email,my_extra_field) 
                ...
```

Gives error about 4 parameters and 5 given.

Option 2:

```
if form.is_valid():
                user = form.cleaned_data['user']
                password = form.cleaned_data['password']
                email = form.cleaned_data['email']
                connect('reborn')
                m = User.create_user(user,password,email)
                m.gold=500
                m.save()
                return HttpResponse(m)
                e.gold = 500
                e.save()
                #john.save()
                #return HttpResponse("Usuari nou creat")
                return render(request, 'game/welcomeuser.html', {
                    'user': user,
                })
```

Gives error save is not method of User Object.

No idea how to fix this !! I readed the manual but I can't discover the solution in the mongoengine docs hosted in readthedocs.com

Answer (score 1):

you use mongoengine.django.auth.User. It contain common fields of user model  like

- first_name
- last_name
- password
- username
- ...

and if you want, you can add more fields this way

```
from mongoengine.django.auth import User
from mongoengine import *

class MyUser(User):
    sex = StringField(default='M',max_length=1)# M-> male, F-> female       
    date_of_birth = DateTimeField()
    [...]
```